# Block emails with "This message has no content"

Tags: iphone, email, spam

Emails that only contain a hyperlink show up in my iPhone email inbox saying "This message has no content" (yet another terse and inaccurate error message, thanks Apple) Every single person who knows anything about computers could tell you that this is 100% certainly a spam/malware/phishing/botnet hyperlink. I don't want them in my inbox. Even if someone I knew sent me just a hyperlink I would never trust it. Do any of the email services offer a way to filter out hyperlink only messages, the ones they don't catch in their spam filtering? Is there a way in iPhone Email to filter these out or send them to a spam folder?

Answer (score 1):

iOS does not support custom Mail rules at the time of writing. You will need to set up a rule like this on the server which is delivering the mail to your device.